# Is it possible to maintain flat input structure with nestjs/graphql Args?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have a simple query:

```js
@Query(() => ProfileOutput)
async profile(@Args('id') id: string) {
  return await this.profileFacade.findProfileById(input.id);
}
```

The problem is that I want to apply `@IsMongoId()` from `class-validator` for the `id` here. I do not want to create new `@InputType` here, because I do not want to change API specification. Is there a way to apply validator like `@IsMongoId` here without the need to change query definition for frontend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone seeking an answer I found a feature called [dedicated argument class](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/resolvers#dedicated-arguments-class). Instead of creating new input type as I thought like this:

```js
@InputType()
export class MongoIdBaseInput {
  @IsMongoId()
  @Field()
  id: string;
}

@Query(() => ProfileOutput)
async profile(@Args('data') input: MongoIdBaseInput) {
  return await this.profileFacade.findProfileById(input.id);
}
```

We can define it almost the same, but annotate input with `ArgsType` it will maintain flat structure of args for us:

```js
@ArgsType()
export class MongoIdBaseInput {
  @IsMongoId()
  @Field()
  id: string;
}

@Query(() => ProfileOutput)
async profile(@Args() input: MongoIdBaseInput) {
  return await this.profileFacade.findProfileById(input.id);
}
```